# Pantheon Files opens Home folder when clicking Trash in Launcher

Tags: 12.04, files, pantheon

I switched from Nautilus to Marlin but was no longer under development so switched to Pantheon Files, whose now under Elementary OS developers. But whenever I click the Trash Icon from Launcher, Phanteon files opens the Home Folder. Is it a bug that I need to file this to it's developers or can someone here can help me?

using **Pantheon Files 0.1** on my **12.04 precise.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

google was nice to me and solved my own problem. for those of you having the same problem, you need to check some lines in your mimeapps.list:

i suggest to backup first. go to `~/.local/share/applications/`, copy then rename pasted file of `mimeapps.list` to `mimeapps.list.backup`

open the original file, look for this line:

```
x-scheme-handler/trash=marlin.desktop
```

if your using nautilus, it must be `trash=nautilus.desktop`

make that line look like this (i'm using Pantheon File manager):

```
x-scheme-handler/trash=pantheon-trash.desktop
```

and `pantheon-trash.desktop` file must be on the same directory (~/.local/share/applications)

here's what `pantheon-trash.desktop` file looks like:

```
[Desktop Entry]

Name=Trash Folder
Comment=Open your personal trash folder
TryExec=pantheon-files
Exec=pantheon-files trash:///
Icon=trash
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Core;
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=pantheon-files
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=pantheon-files
Name[en_PH]=pantheon-trash
```

here's my source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1861067